# How to use swipe refresh with recyclerivew

Tags: android

I have use swipe resfresh with recyclerivew. but I see one problem. I can't scroll my recyclerivew up. I can scroll recyclerview down normally but every time I try to scroll up it will not scroll it up it is work the function swift refresh how ever I am not scrol up to the top yet.
Here is my xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/buslayout"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      >

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          >
          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```